# Add user input to Array in steps C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

I've got a task in school saying that I'm supposed to create a program similar to a backpack where I'm supposed to use an array and a list.

Function of the backpack is to be able to put 4 objects into the smaller compartment (`ytterfack`) and then put unlimited amount of objects into the large compartment (`stora facket`).

I'd like it to work with a menu where the user can put one item into the (`ytterfack`) and if the user want to, switch over to the (`stora fack`) and put an item into that one. That is, I'm trying to avoid having a for-loop for the (`ytterfack`) which would mean that the user get the choice of puttin 4 objects strait away into the (`ytterfack`).

Is there a way to create an array and let the user put the elements inside one at a time and even get a message out when it's full?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("\tVälkommen till Ryggsäcken!!\n");
        Console.WriteLine("\t[1] Lägg till ett föremål i det stora facket");
        Console.WriteLine("\t[2] Lägg till ett föremål i ytterfacket");
        Console.WriteLine("\t[3] Skriv ut innehållet i stora facket");
        Console.WriteLine("\t[4] Skriv ut innehållet i ytterfacket");
        Console.WriteLine("\t[5] Rensa innehållet i stora facket");
        Console.WriteLine("\t[6] Rensa innehållet i ytterfacket");
        Console.WriteLine("\t[7] Avsluta\n");

        string[] ytterFack = new string[4];
        List<string> storaFacket = new List<string> { };
        int i = 0;

        bool kör = true;

        do 
        {
            Console.Write("\n\tVälj punkt från menyn: ");
            int menyVal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (menyVal) 
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.Write("\n\tSkriv in ett föremål: ");
                    storaFacket.Add(Console.ReadLine());
                    //Console.WriteLine("\n\tDu har lagt in " +  + " Tack!\n");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.Write("\n\tSkriv in ett föremål: ");
                    ytterFack[i] = Console.ReadLine();
                    //Console.WriteLine("\n\tDu har lagt in " + ytterFack[i] + " Tack!\n");
                    break;

                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("\tInnehållet i stora facket är:");
                    foreach (string item in storaFacket)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\t" + item);
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Console.WriteLine("\tInnehållet i ytterfacket är:");
                    foreach (string item in ytterFack)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\t" + item);
                    }
                    break;
                case 5:
                    storaFacket.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("\tNu är stora facket tömt!\n");
                    break;
                case 6:
                    Array.Clear(ytterFack, 0, ytterFack.Length);
                    Console.WriteLine("\tNu är ytterfacket tömt!\n");
                    break;
                case 7:
                    kör = false;
                    break; 
                default:
                    break;

            }
        }
        while (kör);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry bout the code.....it's not complete as u can see but I wanted to give you guys a hint of what it's about to become.

Comment: You can implement stack logic, without using for loop. It will require only few variable that need to incremented and decremented.

Comment: Ok, I'll see what i can find out about stack logic, thx

Comment: It appears you have the shell for this well in hand. In case 1: you are adding properly to the list because there is no limit. In case 2: this adds to the small compartment, your current code will only add 1 item here because “i” never gets incremented. Also it is here where you might want to check to see if the small compartment (Array `ytterFack`) is full with 4 items before adding a 5th one. Just a thought.

Comment: The is why you use a List() object instead of an array[]. Lists object have an add method while arrays don't.

Comment: Thx John, my problem is exactly that.
How do I get the array to accept more objects, is it possible and if so how do i get the [i] to increment with each input WITHOUT using a for-loop??

Comment: I've been trying to find an answer to this for two days now.
The good thing is that I'm beeing introduced to stackoverflow :)

Comment: Glad to help. one more thing you will need to consider is bad input from the user when they make a selection. An non-checked  `Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());` will crash your program if the user enters letters and not numbers . Welcome to SO. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is what it became.

I would appreciate a comment or two about it, what can I do better or in a easier way??

```
        Console.WriteLine("\tVälkommen till Ryggsäcken!!\n");
        Console.WriteLine("\t[1] Lägg till ett föremål i det stora facket");
        Console.WriteLine("\t[2] Lägg till ett föremål i ytterfacket");
        Console.WriteLine("\t[3] Skriv ut innehållet i stora facket");
        Console.WriteLine("\t[4] Skriv ut innehållet i ytterfacket");
        Console.WriteLine("\t[5] Rensa innehållet i stora facket");
        Console.WriteLine("\t[6] Rensa innehållet i ytterfacket");
        Console.WriteLine("\t[7] Avsluta\n");

        string[] ytterFack = new string[4];
        List<string> storaFacket = new List<string> { };
        int i = 0;

        bool kör = true;

        do 
        {
            Console.Write("\n\tVälj punkt från menyn: ");

            try
            {
                int menyVal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                switch (menyVal)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.Write("\n\tSkriv in ett föremål: ");
                        storaFacket.Add(Console.ReadLine());
                        //Console.WriteLine("\n\tDu har lagt in " +  + " Tack!\n");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.Write("\n\tSkriv in ett föremål: ");

                        if (ytterFack[0] == null)
                        {
                            ytterFack[0] = Console.ReadLine();
                            break;
                        }

                        else if (ytterFack[1] == null)
                        {
                            ytterFack[1] = Console.ReadLine();
                            break;
                        }
                        else if (ytterFack[2] == null)
                        {
                            ytterFack[2] = Console.ReadLine();
                            break;
                        }
                        else if (ytterFack[3] == null)
                        {
                            ytterFack[3] = Console.ReadLine();
                            break;
                        }


                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("\n\tFacket är fullt och måste tömmas innan du kan lägga ner föremål här.");
                            break;
                        }
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\tInnehållet i stora facket är:\n");
                        foreach (string item in storaFacket)
                        {
                                Console.WriteLine("\t" + item);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\tInnehållet i ytterfacket är:\n");
                        foreach (string item in ytterFack)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("\t" + item);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        storaFacket.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\tNu är stora facket tömt!\n");
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        Array.Clear(ytterFack, 0, ytterFack.Length);
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\tNu är ytterfacket tömt!\n");
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        kör = false;
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\tDu måste välja från menyn, [1] - [7]");
                        break;

                }
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n\tDu kan bara mata in ett val (en siffra) från menyn!");
            }
        }
        while (kör);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing everything in `Main()`, start by modeling your `BackPack` as a separate class - this way you can implement and apply the constraints (like 4 items max) consistently, even if you use a `List<string>` for both:

```
public class BackPack
{
    private List<string> ytterFacket = new List<string>();
    public List<string> YtterFacket
    {
        get {
            return ytterFacket;
        }
    }

    private List<string> storaFacket = new List<string>();
    public List<string> StoraFacket
    {
        get {
            return storaFacket;
        }
    }

    public string PutIntoYtterFacket(string item)
    {
        if (ytterFacket.Count < 4)
        {
            ytterFacket.Add(item);
            return string.Format("Du har lagt in {0}! Tack!", item);
        }
        return string.Format("Kan inte lägge till {0}, gräns nådd", item);
    }

    public string PutIntoStoraFacket(string item)
    {
        storaFacket.Add(item);
        return string.Format("Du har lagt in {0}! Tack!", item);
    }

    public string ClearYtterFacket()
    {
        ytterFacket.Clear();
        return "Nu är ytterfacket tömt!";
    }

    public string ClearStoraFacket()
    {
        storaFacket.Clear();
        return "Nu är storafacket tömt!";
    }
}
```

So the case of adding to `ytterFacket` becomes (assuming `fjallraven` is an instance of the `BackPack` class):

```
Console.Write("\n\tSkriv in ett föremål: ");
fjallraven.PutIntoYtterFacket(Console.ReadLine());
```

You don't have to do error handling in the `case` block, the `BackPack` instance  will do it for you! (Sorry for the error strings, my Swedish is a bit rusty)

Comment: Thx, but a part of the assignment is to use Array for the smaller compartment and List for the bigger one.
But I really like your solution.

Comment: @Tarbh Fair enough, you could do that as well - I was more trying to convey the idea of encapsulating the *behavior* of the backpack in a separate class

Comment: It's a very good example for me as a student and I appreciate it alot, thx